# $f(n)=O(n^{\log_{b}a-\epsilon})\Rightarrow f(n)=o(n^{\log_{b}a})$?

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

In the first case of the master theorem we have:

$f(n)=O(n^{\log_{b}a-\epsilon})$. Isn't this equivalent to $f(n)=o(n^{\log_{b}a})$?

I haven't tried to formalize this but it seems intuitive (With my current understanding of big O notation, which may be flawed). However i'm sure this is not the case, since if it was that's how it would be formulated. Can someone supply a counter example?

Comment: Does the result hod for all $\epsilon >0$?

Comment: $f(n)=O(n^{\log_{b}a-\epsilon})\Rightarrow T(n)=\Theta(n^{\log_{b}a})$ For some $\epsilon>0$

Comment: So you are confused on how to formally show this? Are you familiar with the formal definitions for each of the landau symbols?

Comment: So this is in fact true? If so I'll try to prove it.

Comment: I believe so if $\epsilon$ is fixed. The argument shouldn't be too long. Think about how your bigO estimate can be used in the limit expression  in the definition of the littleO expression

Comment: Let $a,\epsilon>0 f(n)=O(n^{a-\epsilon})\iff f(n)=o(n^{a})$

Proof: $\Leftarrow$ is trivial. In the other direction, We have a constant c and some $N_{1}\in\mathbb{N}$ S.T. $\forall n>N f(n)\leq c\cdot n^{a-\epsilon}. $

Let us show $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(n)}{n^{a}}=0$.Let $\epsilon_{0}>0$. Define $N_{2}=\left(\frac{c}{\epsilon_{0}}\right)^{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}$ and take$ N=max\{N_{1},N_{2}\}$ and we have $\frac{f(n)}{n^{a}}\leq\frac{c}{n^{\epsilon}}<\epsilon_{0}$

Comment: Thats pretty much what I did in my head. Seems correct.